# Does NDK support C++14?

Tags: c++11, android-ndk, c++14, bionic

Currently working on something where I need to develop some feature using C++14, but still wondering on whether it can be supported by Bionic & NDK??

From [Bionic Wiki Status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bionic_%28software%29#cite_note-status-9), C++11 featureshas been implemented/included into Bionic. Only catch is, it is done Android Oreo onwards (which is totally fine for my development :p )

**So my question would be:**

- Please guide me, Am I missing something here with Bionic Status? The status I'm checking is correct?
- If no C++14 support in Bionic, Will C++14 features be included/implemented into Bionic any next release soon? Is there any announcement on this?

Comment: Bionic is the standard **C** library. It cannot support any C++ std library features let alone C++14. Are you asking only for NDK?

Comment: I'm not sure how C++14 relates to Bionic(?). The STL implementation for the NDK is libc++. Could you elaborate on what you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, I totally agree that bionic is C library. I could be wrong, correct me if I'm: If I have developed some lib using NDK with C++14 APIs, and I'm deploying it using a app, will it still run, if Bionic does not have C++14 support. (I will update the question accordingly if required.)

Comment: Whether the NDK supports C++14 depends on which version on the NDK you're using. If you're using the latest one (currently 19c), then the answer is yes.

Comment: _"If I have developed some lib using NDK with C++14 APIs, and I'm deploying it using a app, will it still run"_. Yes, what matters is the NDK version you use when you build. As explained in the documentation: _"On Android, the libc++ used by the NDK is not part of the OS. This gives NDK users access to the latest libc++ features and bug fixes even when targeting old versions of Android. The trade-off is that if you use libc++_shared.so, you must include it in your APK. If you're building your application with Gradle this is handled automatically."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bionic is the standard C library. It does not support any C++ std library features let alone C++14.

If you are asking about NDK, then as per the [cpp-support](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support) page for NDK, LLVM's libc++ is the C++ standard library that has been used by the Android OS since Lollipop and this supports C++17 features.

[image]

Comment: I have a doubt,in regards to integration & execution. If you see my comment above, I have described a scenario. I'm not sure whether I'm correct or not.